# argument --max-dispatches-per-second: invalid float value: '6/m'

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-tasks

I am using `cloud tasks`, I want to set `maxDispatchesPerSecond` to `6/m`.

when I try to update my app engine queue with below command:

```
☁  rate-limit [master] ⚡  gcloud beta tasks queues update-app-engine-queue cloud-tasks-rate-limit --max-dispatches-per-second='6/m'
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.tasks.queues.update-app-engine-queue) argument --max-dispatches-per-second: invalid float value: '6/m'
Usage: gcloud beta tasks queues update-app-engine-queue QUEUE [optional flags]
  optional flags may be  --clear-max-attempts | --clear-max-backoff |
                         --clear-max-concurrent-dispatches |
                         --clear-max-dispatches-per-second |
                         --clear-max-doublings | --clear-max-retry-duration |
                         --clear-min-backoff | --clear-routing-override |
                         --help | --max-attempts | --max-backoff |
                         --max-concurrent-dispatches |
                         --max-dispatches-per-second | --max-doublings |
                         --max-retry-duration | --min-backoff |
                         --routing-override

For detailed information on this command and its flags, run:
  gcloud beta tasks queues update-app-engine-queue --help
```

How can I to this?

Answer (score 1):

The error it's giving you is:

> ERROR: (gcloud.beta.tasks.queues.update-app-engine-queue) argument --max-dispatches-per-second: invalid float value: '6/m'

'6/m' isn't a valid value.  It requires a floating point value.  Compute the value you want, and just enter that number.

Comment: I want to dispatch a task every 30 seconds. Is that means the value of `maxDispatchesPerSecond ` should be 2/60 = 0.033333?

Comment: I don't know - I've never used gcloud in tandem with Cloud Tasks.  I've only ever used it programmatically, and only to schedule some work to happen once at a later time.

Comment: 1 / 30 seconds = 2 dispatches per second.
.0333 looks like 2 requests per minute.