# How to trigger background cloud function with specific duration?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I use Cloud pub/sub and Cloud Functions.

Now, I want to publish a message to a topic which will trigger a background cloud function.

But I want to trigger my cloud function after a specific duration, like 30 seconds later.

How can I do this?

**update:**

Here is my architecture, is it correct?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now, I want to publish a message to a topic which will trigger a
>   background cloud function. But I want to trigger my cloud function after a specific duration, like 30 seconds later.

If you setup PubSub to trigger Cloud Functions on publish events, Cloud Functions will be triggered almost immediately. There is no method to insert a delay.

You will need to implement your code as several major steps:

1. Setup PubSub Topic and Subscriptions. Do not trigger Cloud Functions on new messages. Messages will just sit waiting for delivery. Send messages to this topic.
2. Create a Cloud Function that processes PubSub subscriptions. Pull messages and process.
3. Use another service such as Cloud Tasks, Cloud Scheduler or App Engine Tasks to trigger your Cloud function after your desired delay.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain about step 2? How to process pubsub subscriptions? Do you mean I should set every message a execute timestamp attribute, and the cloud function re-publish the message which does not arrive the execute timestamp? How can I control the frequency of re-publishing a message? I mean re-publish message every 10 seconds?

Comment: Item 2. You need to write a cloud function that is triggered by your scheduler (e.g. HTTP Trigger) after your selected wait time. The function reads messages on the PubSub subcription. I did not say anything about republishing the message, just process the messages. Don't over complicate this.

Comment: I have updated my question. Please take a look. I use app engine cron job + app engine cron job handler instead of cloud scheduler + cloud function. How about my architecture. Is any problem?

Comment: Don't change questions once you have received an answer. Revert the question back and then create a new question. Others might not understand the changes and why the answers don't make sense with your new information.

Comment: Sorry. Seems to be a departure from the subject. I think I know what you mean. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Cloud Tasks](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/) to schedule some work to happen on a delay.

Comment: Thanks. I found this. But there is a issue when I try to set `maxDispatchesPerSecond` property. Please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55098392/argument-max-dispatches-per-second-invalid-float-value-6-m